# Python: substituting a regular expression into a string to be used as a regular expression

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a string:

```
s = 'This is a number -N-'
```

I want to substitute the `-N-` placeholder for a regular expression:

```
s = 'This is a number (\d+)'
```

So I can later use `s` as a regular expression to match against another string:

```
re.match(s, 'This is a number 2')
```

However, I'm not able to get s to substitute in a regular expression that doesn't escape the slash:

```
re.sub('-N-', r'(\d+)', 'This is a number -N-')
# returns 'This is a num (\\d+)'
```

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong here. Thanks!

Comment: Couldn't you just use a string method? `.format`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your string contains only single `\`, use `print` to see the actual string output:

`str` version:

```
>>> print re.sub(r'-N-', r'(\d+)', 'This is a number -N-')
This is a number (\d+)
```

`repr` versions:

```
>>> re.sub(r'-N-', r'(\d+)', 'This is a number -N-')
'This is a number (\\d+)'
>>> print repr(re.sub(r'-N-', r'(\d+)', 'This is a number -N-'))
'This is a number (\\d+)'
```

so, your regex is going to work fine:

```
>>> patt = re.compile(re.sub(r'-N-', r'(\d+)', 'This is a number -N-'))
>>> patt.match('This is a number 20').group(1)
'20'
>>> regex = re.sub(r'-N-', r'(\d+)', 'This is a number -N-')
>>> re.match(regex, 'This is a number 20').group(1)
'20'
```

For more info: [`Difference between __str__ and __repr__ in Python`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr-in-python)

Comment: I'm not able to take the result of the re.sub() and apply it as a regular expression on the subsequent re.match. Can you verify that it works?

Answer (score -1):

Why not just use a replace?

```
 s.replace('-N-','(\d+)')
```

Comment: according to my tests that also escapes the slash